# How to keep Meteor server running?

Tags: amazon-web-services, meteor, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-14.04

A Meteor app is on an Amazon AWS EC2 instance running Ubuntu.

Once logged in remotely via SSH and starting up the app, everything runs fine.

But as soon as the terminal window closes, it seems to shut down the app and it is no longer available in the browser.

How do you make the app continue to run after the terminal window has been closed?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4004/how-can-i-close-a-terminal-without-killing-the-command-running-in-it

Comment: use `screen`.  Install it with `sudo apt-get install screen` --  Basically, `screen` provides a virtual terminal that you can safely disconnect from with `Ctrl-A+Ctrl-D` but will not terminate the running programs.  You can reconnect later with `screen -D -R`

Comment: General advice for such cases is to use forever.js or another supervisor (i.e. supervisord) to keep your applications working in a production environment.